# php - http referer and preg_match

Tags: php, referer

I'm currently trying to work with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
but i don't get this to work...

Heres my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_ERROR);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    $ref        = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
else
    $ref = '';
$id = 0;

if (preg_match('~http://www\.domain1\.com~', $ref))
    $id = 1;
else if(preg_match('~http://www\.domain2\.com~', $ref))
    $id = 2;    
else if(preg_match('~http://www\.domain3\.com~', $ref))
    $id = 3;
else if(preg_match('~http://www\.domain4\.com~', $ref)  )
    $id = 4;

echo $id;   
?>
```

Any Idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Start by logging `$ref` to see what it actually contains

Comment: This is certainly "working", as in "doing something". What exactly are the values of `$ref` and what does or doesn't it do that you expect it to?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is ok, actually what do you want to get from it?

Comment: i wan't know what was the last site, and if the last site was xxx the ID should be 1 for example.
but the id is everytime 0....
echo $ref;
is working, it shows that the last domain was domain1.com 
but $id isn't 1 then ..

Comment: Step 0: Figure out what your values are and how exactly they behave in your code. I.e. `var_dump($ref)`, then go from there.

Answer (score -2):

Change all your regex patterns, '~' to '/' and try again.
You also need to slash your '/', see example.

As in:

```
if (preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.domain1\.com/', $ref))
    $id = 1;
```

Comment: Nope, the regex in the question is fine. Preferred in this case, in fact.

Comment: ~ is an allowed delimiter, it may not be the problem.

Comment: @KevinLabécot Thanks, I just learned something. I always used '/' as a delimiter because it's the most used in examples. I found this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), and understand why '~' is preferred in this case.